# I am having issue printing receipt in Windows form C#

Tags: c#, printing, desktop

I am making desktop application in C#. when I try to print receipts, everything on the form except Grid gets fade. Actually, I'm am hiding some content before printing form. I've used wait function to solve this problem but not working that way. How can I solve this?

1st receipt in picture is printed receipt and 2nd one is Form:

[image: 1st receipt in picture is printed receipt and 2nd one is Form]

Code:

```
 private void PrintFormat(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            if(true)    // Formating form to print
            {
                GridView.Height = 350;
                GridView.Visible = true;
                MsgLabel.Visible = false;
                ProMsg.Visible = false;
                ProductPanel.Visible = false;
                BillPanel.Visible = false;
                SaveButton.Visible = false;
                DiscardButton.Visible = false;
                ThanksLabel.Visible = true;
                this.FormBorderStyle = 0;
                FillGrid(sender, e);
            }
        }

Bitmap bitmap;

        private void PrintForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            this.Enabled = false;
            WaitSomeTime();

            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height, g);
            Graphics mg = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            mg.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, this.Size);
            PrintPreviewDialog.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            //Print the contents.
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
        }
        public async void WaitSomeTime()
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            this.Enabled = true;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
```

Comment: try disabling the this.Enabled = false as it might result in grayed controls. Other thing I can think of is that font color might not be black, and print preview interprets it as gray, so make sure font color is black;

Comment: Thanks bro, your suggestion helped me through

Comment: I tried as you suggested, the image did not seem to be blur on PC but now I got printer and when I tried to print the receipt, print is hardly understandable. Help me through if you can. @frno